# How to parse an XML file to get tag values and handle greater than and double quote characters?

Tags: windows, string, batch-file

How could I extract information from an XML file using batch files?

This is the code I am trying:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "xmlFile=%~1"
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (%xmlFile%) do (
    call :f_extractData "%%A"
)
:f_extractData
set line=%1
if not x%line:00-24=%==x%line% (
    if not x%line:precipitacion=%==x%line% (
        set data=%1:"=%
        echo.%data%
    )
)
EXIT /b
endlocal
:EOF
```

But it fails when reading the following lines:

```
<prob_precipitacion periodo="00-24"></prob_precipitacion>
<prob_precipitacion periodo="00-24">0</prob_precipitacion>
<prob_precipitacion periodo="00-24">25</prob_precipitacion>
```

The result values should be 0 for the first line, 0 for the second line and 25 for the third line. But my tries of extracting part of the string using

```
set data="%data:~37,-22%"
```

fails on those lines. I guess it fails because of the `>` and `"` characters. But I don't know how could I remove those characters to manage with this.

Any ideas?

Here is the full xml I am using to test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15" ?>
<root id="41091" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.aemet.es/xsd/localidades.xsd">
<origen>
    <productor>Agencia Estatal de Meteorología - AEMET. Gobierno de España</productor>
    <web>http://www.aemet.es</web>
    <enlace>http://www.aemet.es/es/eltiempo/prediccion/municipios/sevilla-id41091</enlace>
    <language>es</language>
    <copyright>&#169; AEMET. Autorizado el uso de la información y su reproducción citando a AEMET como autora de la misma.</copyright>
    <nota_legal>http://www.aemet.es/es/nota_legal</nota_legal>
</origen>
<elaborado>2014-12-17T20:20:02</elaborado>
<nombre>Sevilla</nombre>
<provincia>Sevilla</provincia>
<prediccion>
    <dia fecha="2014-12-17">
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-24"></prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-12"></prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="12-24">0</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-06"></prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="06-12"></prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="12-18">0</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="18-24">0</prob_precipitacion>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-24"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-12"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="12-24"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-06"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="06-12"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="12-18"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="18-24"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-24" descripcion=""></estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-12" descripcion=""></estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="12-24" descripcion="Despejado">11</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-06" descripcion=""></estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="06-12" descripcion=""></estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="12-18" descripcion="Despejado">11</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="18-24" descripcion="Despejado">11n</estado_cielo>
        <viento periodo="00-24">
            <direccion></direccion>
            <velocidad></velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="00-12">
            <direccion></direccion>
            <velocidad></velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="12-24">
            <direccion>C</direccion>
            <velocidad>0</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="00-06">
            <direccion></direccion>
            <velocidad></velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="06-12">
            <direccion>C</direccion>
            <velocidad>0</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="12-18">
            <direccion>C</direccion>
            <velocidad>0</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="18-24">
            <direccion>C</direccion>
            <velocidad>0</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <racha_max periodo="00-24"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="00-12"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="12-24"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="00-06"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="06-12"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="12-18"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="18-24"></racha_max>
        <temperatura>
            <maxima>15</maxima>
            <minima>9</minima>
            <dato hora="06"></dato>
            <dato hora="12">15</dato>
            <dato hora="18">14</dato>
            <dato hora="24">9</dato>
        </temperatura>
        <sens_termica>
            <maxima>15</maxima>
            <minima>8</minima>
            <dato hora="06"></dato>
            <dato hora="12">15</dato>
            <dato hora="18">14</dato>
            <dato hora="24">9</dato>
        </sens_termica>
        <humedad_relativa>
            <maxima>95</maxima>
            <minima>60</minima>
            <dato hora="06"></dato>
            <dato hora="12">60</dato>
            <dato hora="18">65</dato>
            <dato hora="24">90</dato>
        </humedad_relativa>
        <uv_max>2</uv_max>
    </dia>
    <dia fecha="2014-12-18">
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-24">25</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-12">0</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="12-24">0</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-06">0</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="06-12">0</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="12-18">0</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="18-24">0</prob_precipitacion>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-24"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-12"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="12-24"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-06"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="06-12"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="12-18"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="18-24"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-24" descripcion="Despejado">11</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-12" descripcion="Despejado">11</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="12-24" descripcion="Despejado">11</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-06" descripcion="Despejado">11n</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="06-12" descripcion="Despejado">11</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="12-18" descripcion="Despejado">11</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="18-24" descripcion="Despejado">11n</estado_cielo>
        <viento periodo="00-24">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>5</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="00-12">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>5</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="12-24">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>5</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="00-06">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>5</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="06-12">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>5</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="12-18">
            <direccion>C</direccion>
            <velocidad>0</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="18-24">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>5</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <racha_max periodo="00-24"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="00-12"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="12-24"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="00-06"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="06-12"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="12-18"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="18-24"></racha_max>
        <temperatura>
            <maxima>18</maxima>
            <minima>7</minima>
            <dato hora="06">8</dato>
            <dato hora="12">16</dato>
            <dato hora="18">14</dato>
            <dato hora="24">8</dato>
        </temperatura>
        <sens_termica>
            <maxima>18</maxima>
            <minima>7</minima>
            <dato hora="06">8</dato>
            <dato hora="12">16</dato>
            <dato hora="18">14</dato>
            <dato hora="24">8</dato>
        </sens_termica>
        <humedad_relativa>
            <maxima>90</maxima>
            <minima>45</minima>
            <dato hora="06">90</dato>
            <dato hora="12">55</dato>
            <dato hora="18">55</dato>
            <dato hora="24">85</dato>
        </humedad_relativa>
        <uv_max>2</uv_max>
    </dia>
    <dia fecha="2014-12-19">
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-24">0</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-12">0</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="12-24">0</prob_precipitacion>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-24"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-12"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="12-24"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-24" descripcion="Despejado">11</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-12" descripcion="Despejado">11</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="12-24" descripcion="Despejado">11</estado_cielo>
        <viento periodo="00-24">
            <direccion>E</direccion>
            <velocidad>5</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="00-12">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>5</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="12-24">
            <direccion>E</direccion>
            <velocidad>5</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <racha_max periodo="00-24"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="00-12"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="12-24"></racha_max>
        <temperatura>
            <maxima>17</maxima>
            <minima>5</minima>
        </temperatura>
        <sens_termica>
            <maxima>17</maxima>
            <minima>3</minima>
        </sens_termica>
        <humedad_relativa>
            <maxima>100</maxima>
            <minima>60</minima>
        </humedad_relativa>
        <uv_max>2</uv_max>
    </dia>
    <dia fecha="2014-12-20">
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-24">0</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-12">0</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="12-24">0</prob_precipitacion>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-24"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-12"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="12-24"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-24" descripcion="Despejado">11</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-12" descripcion="Despejado">11</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="12-24" descripcion="Despejado">11</estado_cielo>
        <viento periodo="00-24">
            <direccion>NE</direccion>
            <velocidad>5</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="00-12">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>10</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="12-24">
            <direccion>NE</direccion>
            <velocidad>5</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <racha_max periodo="00-24"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="00-12"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="12-24"></racha_max>
        <temperatura>
            <maxima>17</maxima>
            <minima>5</minima>
        </temperatura>
        <sens_termica>
            <maxima>17</maxima>
            <minima>3</minima>
        </sens_termica>
        <humedad_relativa>
            <maxima>100</maxima>
            <minima>70</minima>
        </humedad_relativa>
        <uv_max>2</uv_max>
    </dia>
    <dia fecha="2014-12-21">
        <prob_precipitacion>0</prob_precipitacion>
        <cota_nieve_prov></cota_nieve_prov>
        <estado_cielo descripcion="Poco nuboso">12</estado_cielo>
        <viento>
            <direccion>NE</direccion>
            <velocidad>5</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <racha_max></racha_max>
        <temperatura>
            <maxima>16</maxima>
            <minima>4</minima>
        </temperatura>
        <sens_termica>
            <maxima>16</maxima>
            <minima>3</minima>
        </sens_termica>
        <humedad_relativa>
            <maxima>95</maxima>
            <minima>70</minima>
        </humedad_relativa>
        <uv_max>2</uv_max>
    </dia>
    <dia fecha="2014-12-22">
        <prob_precipitacion>0</prob_precipitacion>
        <cota_nieve_prov></cota_nieve_prov>
        <estado_cielo descripcion="Poco nuboso">12</estado_cielo>
        <viento>
            <direccion>E</direccion>
            <velocidad>10</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <racha_max></racha_max>
        <temperatura>
            <maxima>18</maxima>
            <minima>8</minima>
        </temperatura>
        <sens_termica>
            <maxima>18</maxima>
            <minima>7</minima>
        </sens_termica>
        <humedad_relativa>
            <maxima>95</maxima>
            <minima>75</minima>
        </humedad_relativa>
    </dia>
    <dia fecha="2014-12-23">
        <prob_precipitacion>0</prob_precipitacion>
        <cota_nieve_prov></cota_nieve_prov>
        <estado_cielo descripcion="Poco nuboso">12</estado_cielo>
        <viento>
            <direccion>NE</direccion>
            <velocidad>10</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <racha_max></racha_max>
        <temperatura>
            <maxima>17</maxima>
            <minima>6</minima>
        </temperatura>
        <sens_termica>
            <maxima>17</maxima>
            <minima>4</minima>
        </sens_termica>
        <humedad_relativa>
            <maxima>95</maxima>
            <minima>65</minima>
        </humedad_relativa>
    </dia>
</prediccion>
```

Comment: Your test data is not particularly useful since it contains no examples of the target field other that <missing> or "0". The solution I proposed worked for me.

Comment: You are right, sorry for that. I slightly modified the xml file to include a target field value of 25 in one of the lines. Anyway the aim is to find all the lines with <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-24"> and extract the value, (<missing>, "0" or whatever). The solutions provided are not still enough to get this.

Comment: The code I posted most certainly shows that. If the value is missing, it shows 0. If you want "missing" then change the `echo 0` to `echo missing`

Comment: Sorry for my english. I mean that my biggest problem was to manage with strings containing double quotes (and equal and minus signs) to extract the value. But it was my fault as now I realize that my question (and specially my real xml file content) was not fully clear at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss lots of double quotes to avoid that `<`, `>` and `"` are not being interpreted with their special command line meanings.

However, splitting up the lines is done better with **FOR** command instead of environment variable substitutions.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=<>= " %%A in ("%~1") do (

    set "TagName=%%A"
    set "AttributeName=%%B"
    set "AttributeValue=%%~C"
    set "TagValue=%%D"

    if "!TagName!"=="prob_precipitacion" (
        if "!AttributeName!"=="periodo" (
            if "!AttributeValue!"=="00-24" (
                if "!TagValue:~0,1!"=="/" set "TagValue=0"
                echo !TagValue!
            )
        )
    )

    set "TagName="
    set "AttributeName="
    set "AttributeValue="
    set "TagValue="
)
endlocal
```

---

**EDIT:**

By adding the horizontal tab character between equal sign and the space character in the list of delimiter characters, the **for** command with the tokens 1 to 4 would work independent on indentations in XML file.

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=<>=   " %%A in ("%~1") do (
```

There are 5 characters after `delims=`:

1. a left angle bracket,
2. a right angle bracket,
3. an equal sign,
4. a horizontal tab character *(not a sequence of spaces as browser displays)* and
5. a single space character.

The order of the delimiter characters is important as otherwise command line interpreter would exit batch script because of a syntax error.

With this modification the XML lines can be indented with spaces or with tabs or not indented at all and the result would be nevertheless always identical.

Comment: I tried this code but unfortunately it doesn't work. It shows no outputs at all. Then I slightly modified the code including an echo after the first if and it seems that even this condition is not validated.

Comment: In other words my code worked perfect for the XML content block posted by you in question initially, but did not work with your XML file as the lines are different added to question later. Next time please post real file content from the beginning. That saves our and your time. Hint: Changing `tokens=1-4` to `tokens=2-5` would be all required to get my code working on your XML file with something left to tag `prob_precipitacion` not posted in question.

Comment: Yes Mofi, it was not your fault or errors in your code. It was my fault not to include all the information at the beginning. As I previously commented I was trying to learn how to manage with these special string variables in general. Your codes, both, were very useful. Sorry for not voting up your answers but I have no enough privileges yet.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=1,3,4delims=<> " %%a IN ('findstr /L "prob_precipitacion" q27584352.txt^|findstr /L /c:"periodo=\"00-24\"" ') DO (
 IF "%%c"=="" (ECHO 0) ELSE (ECHO %%b)
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q27584352.txt` containing your data for my testing.

In your posted code, after the `for /f .. %%A..` loop, batch will simply execute the next line and the next until it actually terminates on the `exit/b`, having executed the `:f_extractData` subroutine one last time, using the first parameter to the program as `%1`. Batch has no concept of `sections` and does not stop or magically leap over labelled routines.

The label `:EOF` is inbuilt into `cmd` - it means "end of this batch file" and need not be explicitly declared (in fact, I believe it's very bad practice to delcare it)

Simply executing

```
goto :eof
```

after your `for...%%A...` will exit the program - batch knows where `:eof` is (but the colon is compulsory.)

You can also use `goto :eof` in place of `exit /b` in this instance. Reaching `eof` terminates the subroutine and hence batch reurns to the instaruction after the `call`.

**Edited to include `^|findstr /L /c:"periodo=\"00-24\""` in the filter to eliminate the lines which do not contain `periodo="00-24"`**

Leaves 4 lines, not 7 that fit the requirement.

Comment: This solution solves part of my problem. But as you can see my xml file, some of the lines include periodo="00-24" and others include periodo="00-12" . I need to identify the first case but I don't know how to manage with these strings including double quotes (or maybe the problem is the equal or the minus sign)

Comment: I've shown you that - by piping the first filter using `^|findstr /L /c:"periodo=\"00-24\""` The first filters for "prob_precipitacion", the second filters out lines that do not contain the `/l` literal `c:` (constant string) `periodo=\"00-24\"` where the `\` escapes the `"` and includes it into the string-to-match.

Comment: Thanks Magoo. The second part of the filter solves part of the problem, and I learned with that how to escape double quotes. You both are right. I was not clear at the beginning of the full requirement of the data. I really was not sure of those requirements then. My main aim was, in general, to manage with string variables including special characters like `" -  < >` or `=` .

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution using most of the code in the second answer (Mofi's answer) with some changes. This is the final code that list the seven target values I was looking for in the xml file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq tokens=1-5 delims=<>= " %%A in ("aemet20141217.xml") do (
set "TagName=%%B"
set "AttributeName=%%C"
set "AttributeValue=%%D"
set "TagValue=%%E"

if "!TagName!"=="prob_precipitacion" (
    if "!AttributeName!"=="periodo" (
        if "!AttributeValue!"==""00-24"" (
            if "!TagValue:~0,1!"=="/" set "TagValue=0"
            echo !TagValue!
        )
    ) 
    if "!AttributeName!" NEQ "periodo" (
    set "TagValue=!AttributeName!"
    if "!AttributeName:~0,1!"=="/" set "TagValue=0"
    echo !TagValue!
    )
)
set "TagName="
set "AttributeName="
set "AttributeValue="
set "TagValue="
)
endlocal
```

NOTE: The split in the for /F line results in 5 items (not 4 as predicted by the original code of Mofi) due to a first empty item. That is the main reason why the original code didn't works.